# How to declare and use a property that's not transferred to/from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

In my data model I have an entity with two numeric properties, mapped to a table with appropriate columns, and one additional property, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rectangles")
public class Rectangle {

    private int sideA;
    private int sideB;

    @Basic public int getSideA() { return sideA; }
    @Basic public int getSideB() { return sideB; }

    //What annotations should I use here?
    public int getArea() { return sideA * sideB; }

    //...corresponding setters for sideA and sideB
    ...
}
```

Now, my question is: can I (how?) mark a property `Area` so it would be still calculated **by application** (its getter), would not have corresponding column in database, but could be used (referenced by name) in queries, criteria builder API, etc.? If I mark it `@Transient`, I cannot use it in queries. If I annotate it in any other way, I need to map it to some column. What am I missing? Can it be done with regular JPA? With Hibernate? Or not at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Java-computed property in queries: queries are translated to SQL and executed by your database, which doesn't know and care about your Java code.

You can add an additional persistent field to your entity, annotated with [Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula). But be careful: modifying sideA and then getting the area will return you the old area, that was computed by the database when the entity was read from the database. Also, Formula is Hibernate-specific. JPA doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the property with `@Transient` which. But keep in mind, that the property is no longer available in your hql query.

Using `@Forumlar` you can use the property inside your query.